# If a linear system has no free variables, then it is consistent: Why is the statement false?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I recently got this question wrong on a test, and I have no clue why. How can a system be inconsistent if there are no free variables?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the "system" $x_1=2, x_1=3$. Are there any free variables?

Answer (score 1):

Two equations (in 2 variables) that happen to be parallel lines form an inconsistent system. There are no free variables. Free variables means that there are infinite solutions. That is not incosistent.

Comment: so a matrix such as [ 2 2 1 ]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[ 2 2 2 ] ?

Comment: Yes, when you put that in your TI and perform RREF (Reduction Row Echelon Form) then you will see the bottom row having 0___0___1  and that is inconsistent and no free variables